# Unity EditorWindow OnGUI doesn't save data for List<string[]> types

Tags: unity-game-engine

It appears that anything I add to a `List<string[]>` will get added, but when I save any scripts and Unity does compiles everything, the items in the list disappears.

Here is a simple class I wrote that just displays a window and adds labels according to how many items are in the list:

```
    public class TestEditorWindow : EditorWindow
    {
        string windowLabel = "Test Window";
        [SerializeField] List<string[]> myList = new List<string[]>();

        [MenuItem("Tools/My Window")]
        static void Init()
        {
            TestEditorWindow myWindow = (TestEditorWindow)GetWindow(typeof(TestEditorWindow));
            myWindow.Show();
       } 

        private void OnGUI()
        {
            GUILayout.Label(windowLabel, EditorStyles.boldLabel);

            EditorGUILayout.Separator();

            GUILayout.BeginVertical("box", GUILayout.ExpandWidth(true));

            for(int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Stupid");
            } 

            if(GUILayout.Button("+", GUILayout.MaxWidth(30)))
            {
                //myList.Add(new string[2]); //<-- Also tried it this way
                myList.Add(new string[] { "" });
            }

            GUILayout.EndVertical();
        }
    }
```

The window shows and every time I hit the button a new label is added to the window, but as soon as Unity compiles anything, the values go away.

If I change the list to `List<string>` it behaves as intended

I've also tried setting up the list like so and got the same results:

```
    [SerializeField] static List<string[]> myList;

    [MenuItem("Tools/My Window")]
    static void Init()
    {
        myList = new List<string[]>();
        TestEditorWindow myWindow = (TestEditorWindow)GetWindow(typeof(TestEditorWindow));
        myWindow.Show();
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong with how I'm loading the list?

Comment: When using `static` in Unity beware - [thar be dragons](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/DomainReloading.html).  Unity is a **CLR Host** whereby it can and will **zap** out the **Primary App Domain** along with all your objects **including singletons** not just during runtime but also whilst using the **Editor**.  See also _[Details of disabling Domain and Scene Reload](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConfigurableEnterPlayModeDetails.html)_.

Comment: ...also Unity Editor Windows are a special beast - the only _state_ you should be saving is a widget's (e.g. textbox) _last value_ **not** a reference to the currently selected object and this is one place you should never use `static`.

Comment: You make some excellent points. Yeah, I'm learning real quick how hairy things can get if you're not paying attention with this stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity cannot serialize multidimensional collections.

There is a work around though.

Create a new class that contains the string array, and create a list using that type.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class StringArray
{
    public string[] array;
}
```

and in your window use:

```
public List<StringArray> myList = new List<StringArray>();
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I was wondering if I did something wrong or if it was a limitation that I ran into.

I actually already went this same direction after posting my question and it worked great. I'll mark this one as the right answer.